# Scrapy / XPATH : finding substring in image url

Tags: xpath, scrapy, substring

I have the following HTML source pattern :

```
<ul class="test_ul">
     <li>
         <img src="https://www.awebsite.com/image_1_a_test.png" />
    </li>  
    <li>
         <img src="https://www.awebsite.com/another_1_b_test.jpg" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now I want to be able to select only the path where the src is pointing to an image which includes the "b_test" substring.

This is what I have as the string for the selector in scapy:

```
".//ul[@class='test_ul']//img[contains(@src,'b_test')]"
```

But this does not seem work and I don't see the error. I'm able to chek for the full name, but not the substring.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it work if you try without the leading `.`?

Comment: No, I'm afraid it does not, as this is just a nested item in a loop and I need the context.

Comment: And just to clarify, the selector works fine down to ..//img . And if I simply use something like ..//img/@src it correctly returns the source url.

Comment: Can you show a runnable example showing the problem? I can't reproduce it, and get the element when testing.

Comment: @PeterK. your context does not change in your loop on each iteration?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't quote to full live example, as that is several pages long. However, although I can't explain why, but just changing the single quotes to double quotes and vice versa, it works now.

Comment: create minimal working example with your problem - without this we can't see and test problem, so we can't help you.

Comment: Your xpath works correctly on Linux command line (xmllint). Post your python code fragment to better clarify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should include `/@src` in order to getting the url path

```
".//ul[@class='test_ul']//img[contains(@src,'b_test')]/@src"
```